# Closing a Sitecore Speak Dialog that was opened from a Rich Text Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-speak-ui

I'm converting a Sheer UI module to SPEAK, and it's generally been pretty painless except for one problem. It's a dialog that opens from a button click in the rich text editor. I can't work out how to close it and return a value.

I've tried looking at the way Sitecore's existing SPEAK dialogs do it. For example `SelectMediaDialog`:

- It has a rule component called `insertButtonRule`.
- The target control is set to `SelectMediaButton` and the trigger is
  set to `click`.
- The condition / action for the associated rule is
  "when `always`, set the dialog return value to component
  `MediaResultsListControl` `selectedItemId`".

This seems fairly straight forward, but I couldn't duplicate it for my application - it just does nothing. I realise that none of the current Sitecore SPEAK dialogs are launched from the rich text editor, so this isn't really a like-for-like comparison. Perhaps it's the way I'm opening the dialog?

Here's the js command that I use to open my dialog (it's basically the same as my old Sheer UI app but with a different URL):

```js
RadEditorCommandList["OpenMyApp"] = function(commandName, editor, tool) 
{
    scEditor = editor; 
    var range = scEditor.getSelection().getRange()

    range.expand("word");
    scEditor.getSelection().selectRange(range)
    var html = scEditor.getSelection().getText().trim();

    scEditor.showExternalDialog(
      "/sitecore/client/MySpeakApp?term=" + escape(html),
      null, //argument
      300, //width
      500, //height
      scMyCallback,
      null,
      "My Speak App",
      true, //modal
      Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Close, // behaviors
      false, //showStatusBar
      false //showTitleBar
    );
};


function scMyCallback(sender, returnValue) 
{
    if (returnValue) 
       scEditor.pasteHtml(returnValue.text);
}
```

Has anyone else written a SPEAK app for the Rich text editor?
Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had to go looking on the Telerik site, and this code is adapted from what I found:

```javascript
var radWindow;

if (window.radWindow)
    radWindow = window.radWindow;
else if (window.frameElement && window.frameElement.radWindow)
    radWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
else
    window.close();

radWindow.Close("My return value");
```

It feels a little messy mixing this in with shiny new SPEAK code, but right now I'm just glad it works.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Comment: This was part of a module that is now available on Github. Here's the code in situ (part of a SPEAK component): https://github.com/TwentyGotoTen/SitecoreThesaurusSpeak/blob/cff9d7a2f2c8ac120db0a2914bca7355505bdffa/SitecoreThesaurus/Sitecore/Shell/Client/ThesaurusDialog/SynonymList.js

Comment: Well, a huge thank you for pointing me to this github repo. It's a very good starting point for something I need to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The select Media dialog is using this line to return the value

```
 window.top.dialogClose(returnValue); //return value is the value you want to return
```

If you try to call this method in your SPEAK page, does it close the dialog?

PS: I have never tried it.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it didn't work, presumably because of the Telerik controls that are involved. See my answer for what I eventually settled on.

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late and you have already solved it :-) 
In SPEAK you can trigger ConfirmationDialog  like this:

```
myConfirmationDialog.CloseClick = "ok";
myConfirmationDialog.hide();
```

(If you where using ConfirmationDialog)